# Hierarchical parameter tree with Windows Forms

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface

Does a control like this exist for Windows Forms?

Basically, there are a bunch of parameters organized in a tree structure. They have different types, so different appropriate controls are displayed next to them.

I believe the application shown (Basler's Pylon Viewer) is Qt-based, but I have no Qt experience so I'm not sure.

I could fake something similar by nesting UserControls, but that's just horrible.

[image: Pylon Viewer Features]

Comment: Have a look at the `PropertyGrid` control, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx